# How to run qt project using fakevim keymap in qtcreator?

Tags: qt, vim, qt-creator, fakevim

I would like to map qq key in FakeVim insert mode or command mode to run the current project. I googled but found nothing.There is option for Ex Command mapping. But I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign "Run" action to "run" ex command in FakeVim configuration.

[image: Ex Command Mapping configuration]

Then put `map qq :run<CR>` line in your `vimrc` file which is read by FakeVim (default is `%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc` on Windows or `~/.vimrc`; the path can be changed in "General" config tab).